# Is the product of Jacobson rings a Jacobson ring?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2783558/660) on Mathematics Stackexchange, but got no answer.

Is the product 
$$
\prod_{i\in I}A_i
$$ 
of a family $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ of [Jacobson rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_ring) 
a Jacobson ring?

(Here "ring" means "commutative ring with one".)

Comment: As already noted in the MSE post: (1) the answer is positive if $I$ is finite. (2) About the case $I = \mathbb{N}$ and $A_i = \mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$, the reference http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm138/fm138114.pdf is useful (but I am unable to infer whether $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$ is a Jacobson ring.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is **no** in general.

Take $R = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{> 0}} \mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$. Then the Jacobson radical of $R$ is $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{> 0}} 2\mathbb{Z}/2^n\mathbb{Z}$, and it contains a non-nilpotent element, namely $(2 + 2^n \mathbb{Z})_n$. Therefore the Jacobson radical of $R$ doesn't coincide with the nilradical of $R$.

All credits go to Georges Elencwajg, see this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90980/what-is-the-dimension-of-the-product-ring-prod-mathbb-z-2n-mathbb-z?rq=1).

**Side note.** Let $J(R)$ denote the Jacobson radical of a  commutative unital ring $R$. Knowing that $x \in J(R)$ holds if and only if $1 + rx \in R^{\times}$ holds for every $r \in R$, the identity $J(\prod_{i \in I} A_i) = \prod_{i \in I} J(A_i)$ is immediate.